# Transaction fails in pay pal sandbox account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have created a pay pal sandbox account via

https://developer.paypal.com

and the account has been created successfully. It automatically creates two account one for buyer and seller in accounts section. I tried to do some test with transactions as my ultimate goal was to get the postback(whether payment success/failure, products purchased) while one the way i planned to do some transaction with sand box account details .

So i went documentation tab at the top of pay after i logged in . Under left hand side "Use paypal with" selected "create button" and chosen "Build your paypal button" it redirects me to this link http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/

From their i got an option of  "Customize & Preview" , a modal pops up gave the merchant email id(sandbox account) and then some fake product details(also checked sandbox checkbox). When i saved a pay pal button generates, when i clicked to took me to the payment section there i gave the credentials of sandbox account i got the error

Please make sure you have entered your email address correctly.
Please re-enter your PayPal password.

but i can able to login with these details in pay pal account.

Dont know whats wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can i get some comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of survey in net, i found the solution for transaction to happen

Binded email should be confirmed to enable transactions.
Give the faciliataor one(mail-facilitator@domain.com) as the amount receiver.
While paying give the seller account details(mail-seller@domain.com).
And the main thing is that prefer US country while creating account.